# Miss you saying or your saying

Tags: phrase-usage

> I miss your saying '' I love you''.
>
> I miss you saying '' I love you''.

Which phrase should  I use after the verb '' miss'' you or your. As far as I searched on the internet I couldn't find any result but I thougt second one is better than the firs one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but have a slightly different nuance in meaning. The first

> I miss your saying '' I love you''.

means that you miss the action of them saying I love you; it is similar to saying "I miss the times when you would say "I love you."" It is those times that you miss. Use this if it is the action itself you miss most.

The second

> I miss you saying '' I love you''.

means that you specifically miss that person saying "I love you." Use this if you want to emphasise more that you miss the person.

As you suggest, the second tends to sound better in informal speech (the first is a little more formal), and also sounds a bit more intimate given the subject matter.

Comment: I would also think *I miss your saying* would be more appropriate to a phrase specific to that person: *I miss your saying "two eyes make five"* for example